# Having difficulty formatting output to 3 decimal places

Tags: java

I'm very new to Java and I'm just trying to get through some class exercises.

I've been given the task of calculating a user's perimeter and area of their circle from a given radius.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Circle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Please enter the radius of your circle below: ");

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    float r =input.nextFloat();

    float p = (float) (2 * Math.PI * r);
    float a = (float) ((Math.PI) * Math.pow(r,2));

    System.out.format("Your perimeter is %.3f", p + " and your area is %.3f", a);

    }
}
```

This is my code so far, and I'm pretty sure it's all I need, but the compiler is throwing the error:

'Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.String'

I've tried playing around with the System.out line a few times but I can't figure out where I'm going wrong!

Any ideas? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5):

`p + " and your area is %.3f"` is being interpreted as a `String` due to [type promotion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2). Use

```
System.out.format("Your perimeter is %.3f and your area is %.3f", p, a);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    System.out.format("Your perimeter is %.3f and your area is %.3f", p, a);
```

The reason is because the format method expects the first arg to be the format string followed by a varargs of objects to printed. You were passing a string as the second argument and you were trying to format it as a float, which caused the exception to be thrown.